Activation functions in Neural Cellular Automata
NCAs aren't necessarily the exact same as neural networks but I am trying to do my own implementation to understand better. Do activation functions (especially in this case) serve only for training or for updating the state of the grid? If we skip training, how are activation functions still relevant?
